# insertion of musical rhythm cell in a text - special characters?

Tags: symbols, characters, music

I'm writing a document using `\documentclass{tufte-book}`

How can I insert in a text special characters specific to music (rhythm cells corresponding to : double eighth note, two eighth notes, black). What is the corresponding package ?

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/music ... Probably `LATEX4Musicians`  is a good point to start with these packages (really I have no idea about).

Comment: There are several possibilities, the easiest being a symbol package like `wasysym`. See https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-write-music-with-latex/ for an overview.

Comment: Please, can you write an example to understand better your question using an image?

Comment: @Sebastiano My problem is solved, I will add as soon as possible a MWE to present the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution to insert musical rhythms in a text:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{musicography}

\begin{document}

the package musicography allows the insertion of rhythms cells as the following example \musSixteenth\ \musCorchea \musCorchea\ \musQuarter\ .

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

Comment: You can use `\musEighth` instead of `\musCorchea` if you're thinking in modern note names (same result).