# Packages and classes for libretti and music

Tags: music

Can you recommend ideal packages and classes for writing libretti in LaTeX? Also, can one include staff notation for music in LaTeX? If so, what are the classes and packages required?

Comment: "Libretti" (in italian language? :-)) For the music there are musixtex and lilypond packages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136571/musixtex-vs-lilypond

Comment: No, in English, but thanks

Comment: I ask a similar question few days ago, and the comments were very useful... see : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531862/insertion-of-musical-rhythm-cell-in-a-text-special-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many packages for the music:

1. `harmony` - https://www.ctan.org/pkg/harmony;
2. `lilyglyphs`: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/luatex/latex/lilyglyphs/documentation/lilyglyphs.pdf;
3. and others packages within of this manual of symbols: http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\usepackage{musicography}`: https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/musicography/musicography.pdf